# Compass overlay over map using osmdroid 6.1

Tags: java, android, osmdroid

I'm using osmdroid 6.1 to add a compass overlay, but it is not displayed on the map. My code is the following:

```java
this.mCompassOverlay = new CompassOverlay(ctx, new InternalCompassOrientationProvider(ctx), map);
        this.mCompassOverlay.enableCompass();
        map.getOverlays().add(this.mCompassOverlay);
```

I expect the compass overlay runs and I can detect the maps orientation, but it does not work

Comment: One possible reason could be that the phone or tablet does not have a compass (i.e. a magnetometer). You also need to call `compassOverlay.enableCompass();`, I think. (And `compassOverlay.disableCompass();` to stop it.)

Comment: Can you explain more details please? On create method I wrote `this.mCompassOverlay = new CompassOverlay(ctx, new InternalCompassOrientationProvider(ctx), map);
        map.getOverlays().add(this.mCompassOverlay);`
onResume I wrote  `this.mCompassOverlay.enableCompass();`
onPause I wrote `this.mCompassOverlay.disableCompass();`